# vue-cli webpack server custom domain

Tags: webpack, server, dns, vue-cli

I am using vue-cli webpack package and I need to set a custom domain on webdev server to connect to API due to CORS related issues. How can I achieve that? Entering localhost:8080 into backend database does not work.
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

Create or edit the `projectRootDir/vue.config.js` file:

```
module.exports: {
    configureWebpack: {
        devServer: {
            host: 'mycustomdomain',
            port: '8080'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This only works if you have an entry like this in your host file: `127.0.0.1 mycustomdomain`